# How to open and close an excel workbook in a python for loop using xlwings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I need to open and close the same workbook in a python `for` loop without necessarily saving the workbook. I tried the following in `xlwings`:

```
import xlwings as xw

for i in range(5):
    print(i)
    book = xw.Book()
    book.app.quit()
```

However this will only run for the first iteration. At the second iteration I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/TEMP/SE/python/ref.py", line 5, in <module>
    book = xw.Book('tree_template.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\aboufira\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\SE\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 533, in __init__
    for wb in app.books:
  File "C:\Users\aboufira\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\SE\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 374, in books
    return Books(impl=self.impl.books)
  File "C:\Users\aboufira\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\SE\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 397, in books
    return Books(xl=self.xl.Workbooks)
  File "C:\Users\aboufira\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\SE\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 313, in xl
    self._xl = get_xl_app_from_hwnd(self._hwnd)
  File "C:\Users\aboufira\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\SE\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 222, in get_xl_app_from_hwnd
    ptr = accessible_object_from_window(child_hwnd)
  File "C:\Users\aboufira\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\SE\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 190, in accessible_object_from_window
    res = oledll.oleacc.AccessibleObjectFromWindow(
  File "_ctypes/callproc.c", line 948, in GetResult
OSError: [WinError -2147467259] Unspecified error
```

Why does this occur? How can I get xlwings to exit out of the application without causing any problems?

Answer (score 1):

Your code was almost correct, use:

```
import xlwings as xw

for i in range(5):
    print(i)
    app = xw.App(visible=True)
    book = xw.Book()
    app.quit()
```

You can also use `app = xw.App(visible=False)` if you want to open a workbook without showing it.

Comment: useful answer. Upvoted. Is it recommenddd close/quit excel app via xlwings? Like what we have in pandas excelwriter .close(), .save() etc. Or I can also just close manually by clicking cross icon

Comment: if I don't quit, would it result in any file corruption or bad zip file error sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to suffice the pop-ups

> app.display_alerts=False